# Blazor app using Adzue App Registration is getting infinite loop after deployment but works locally

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, azure-app-registration

I have a Blazor app that is getting the infinite loop on login. I can't figure it out.

I am using Azure App Registration - this has been working locally.

Local redirects..
http://localhost:54155/signin-oidc

I added https://mycompany/myapp/signin-oidc in the Web Redirect URI. This is what I usually do with apps. But I am getting an infinite login loop now.

The App Registration was generated in Visual Studio automatically when I created the app. It had Access tokens off and ID tokens on.

Edit: I am getting "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again." now.

Answer (score 1):

This needed a client secret to work.

After I added the client secret the app worked.